# Trouble getting matplotlib to produce plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython

I can get matplotlib to work in pylab (ipython --pylab), but when I execute the same command in a python script a plot does not appear. My workspace focus changes from a fullscreened terminal to a Desktop when I run my script, which suggests that it is trying to plot something but failing.

The following code works in `ipython --pylab` but not in my script.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(arange(10))
```

I am on Mac OS X Mountain Lion. **What is causing this to fail when I run a script but not in the interactive prompt?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need `plt.show()` .

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `plt.show()` after `plt.plot(...)`.

`plt.plot()` just makes the plot, `plt.show()` takes the plot you made and displays it on the screen.